# How to setup ajax date picker to Flask app using MySQL database for plotting graph using date filtered data

Tags: python, mysql, ajax, flask, plotly

I am trying to build small web application fetchehing data from MySQL database with help of ajax date filter and applying dates and rendering table and chart in frontend I can able to get Table with my script not able to get chart how to do changes for getting chart and table as well
this is main.py file

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify, flash, redirect
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL, MySQLdb  # pip install flask-mysqldb https://github.com/alexferl/flask-mysqldb

app = Flask(__name__)

app.secret_key = "caircocoders-ednalan"

app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = 'localhost'
app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = 'xxxx'
app.config['MYSQL_DB'] = "battery_voltage"
app.config['MYSQL_CURSORCLASS'] = 'DictCursor'
mysql = MySQL(app)
@app.route('/')
def index():
    cursor= mysql.connection.cursor()
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM voltage ORDER BY date desc")
    orders = cur.fetchall()
    return render_template('index.html', orders=orders)
@app.route("/range", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def range():
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        From = request.form['From']
        to = request.form['to']
        print(From)
        print(to)
        query = "SELECT * FROM voltage WHERE date BETWEEN '{}' AND '{}'".format(From, to)
        cur.execute(query)
        ordersrange = cur.fetchall()
    return jsonify({'htmlresponse': render_template('response.html', ordersrange=ordersrange)})
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True,port="2021")
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Python Flask Date Range Search with jQuery Ajax DatePicker MySQL Database</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css"/>
    <style>
    table, th, td {
      border: 1px solid black;
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <br/>
    <div class="container">
    <h2 align="left">OPSPOD Battery Voltage</h2>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <div class="col-md-2">
    <input type="text" name="From" id="From" class="form-control" placeholder="From Date"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
    <input type="text" name="to" id="to" class="form-control" placeholder="To Date"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
    <input type="button" name="range" id="range" value="Range" class="btn btn-success"/>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <br/>
    <div id="purchase_order">
    <table class="table table-bordered" style="width:40%" align="left" >
    <tr>
        <th width="5%">Date</th>
        <th width="4%">Time</th>
        <th width="4%">voltage</th>
        <th width="4%">ignition</th>
    </tr>
    {% for row in orders %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{row.date}}</td>
        <td>{{row.time}}</td>
        <td>{{row.voltage}}</td>
        <td>{{row.ignition}}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </table>
    </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <!-- Script -->
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.datepicker.setDefaults({
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
        });
        $(function(){
            $("#From").datepicker();
            $("#to").datepicker();
        });
        $('#range').click(function(){
            var From = $('#From').val();
            var to = $('#to').val();
            if(From != '' && to != '')
            {
                $.ajax({
                    url:"/range",
                    method:"POST",
                    data:{From:From, to:to},
                    success:function(data)
                    {
                        $('#purchase_order').html(data);
                        $('#purchase_order').append(data.htmlresponse);

                    }
                });
            }
            else
            {
                alert("Please Select the Date");
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

response.html

```
<table class="table table-bordered" style="width:40%" align="left" >
    <tr>
        <th width="5%">Date</th>
        <th width="4%">Time</th>
        <th width="4%">voltage</th>
        <th width="4%">ignition</th>
    </tr>
    {% for row in ordersrange %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{row.date}}</td>
        <td>{{row.time}}</td>
        <td>{{row.voltage}}</td>
        <td>{{row.ignition}}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

[This is the link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1O4DB_FdJOUDnYO5Meduj4oubBWOD7RLFR1Of3x1PjhQ/edit?usp=sharing) for the  data which I used in MYSQL DB.

With the code above I am able to get the output like this table below but I am trying for graph as well with same date filtering with X-axis time and Y-axis voltage

[image: table image]

Comment: ok i will delete

Comment: yes i am storing my values as date Format: 'dd-mm-yy'  actually I don't know how to set up graph in jQuery with selected date x axis as Time and y axis as voltage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start by addressing your database issues. Storing dates and times as strings is a bad idea as they use more space and cannot be handled as efficiently as native `DATE` / `TIME` types. A date as string '01-12-2022' stored in a `VARCHAR` uses 11 Bytes, whereas if you convert it to `DATE` it is only 3 Bytes. Similarly for your time data - 8 Bytes as `VARCHAR` or 3 Bytes as `TIME`. Even better would be to combine the two together as `DATETIME` requiring only 5 Bytes, but I shall leave that for you to ponder.

```
-- Update dates from dd-mm-yyyy (note 4 digit year) to yyyy-mm-dd
UPDATE `voltage` SET `date` = STR_TO_DATE(`date`, '%d-%m-%Y');
-- If your existing dates have 2 digit year then use
UPDATE `voltage` SET `date` = STR_TO_DATE(`date`, '%d-%m-%y');

-- update the column types
ALTER TABLE `voltage`
    MODIFY COLUMN `date` DATE NOT NULL,
    MODIFY COLUMN `time` TIME NOT NULL;
```

You should also make sure you have a composite index on (`date`, `time`).

To avoid this answer getting too long, I am not going to include the full content of the `index.html` template file but I have made the following changes -

1. `<div id="purchase_order">` to `<div id="voltages">`
2. Added `<div id="chart"></div>` before `<div id="voltages">`
3. Added `<thead>` around the header row and `tbody` around the rest of the table rows
4. Added `<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>` after the 2 jQuery scripts
5. Renamed `From` as `from` in various places

Then the inline script -

```
<script>
const chartLayout = {
    hovermode: 'closest',
    xaxis: {
        type: 'date',
        dtick: 10800000,
        hoverformat: '%H:%M:%S',
        tickformat: '%H:00\n%d %b',
        rangebreaks: [{ pattern: 'hour' }]
    }
};
Plotly.react('chart', [{ x: [/* leaving these for you to figure out */], y: [], line: { simplify: false } }], chartLayout);

$(document).ready(function(){
    $.datepicker.setDefaults({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
    });
    $(function(){
        $("#from").datepicker();
        $("#to").datepicker();
    });
    $('#range').click(function(){
        var from = $('#from').val();
        var to = $('#to').val();
        if(from != '' && to != '')
        {
            $.ajax({
                url:"/range",
                method:"GET",
                data:{from:from, to:to},
                success:function(data)
                {
                    let x = [], y = [], rows = '';
                    for (const row of data) {
                        x[x.length] = `${row.date} ${row.time}`;
                        y[y.length] = row.voltage;
                        rows += `<tr><td>${row.date}</td><td>${row.time}</td><td>${row.voltage}</td><td>${row.ignition}</td></tr>`;
                    }

                    // update table content
                    $('#voltages > table > tbody').html(rows);

                    // update chart
                    Plotly.react('chart', [{ x: x, y: y, line: { simplify: false } }], chartLayout);
                }
            });
        }
        else
        {
            alert("Please Select the Date");
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

And this is the modified `/range` route -

```
@app.route('/range')
def range():
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)

    fromDate = request.args.get('from')
    toDate = request.args.get('to')

    query = """
            SELECT CAST(`date` AS CHAR) AS `date`, CAST(`time` AS CHAR) AS `time`, `voltage`, `ignition`
            FROM voltage
            WHERE date BETWEEN '{}' AND '{}'
            ORDER BY date, time
        """.format(fromDate, toDate)
    cur.execute(query)
    voltages = cur.fetchall()

    return jsonify(voltages)
```

The `date` and `time` have been cast to `CHAR`s in the `SELECT` as `json.dumps()` (used by jsonify) does not like handling them as their native types. You should switch to using parameterized prepared statements to mitigate the current [SQLi vulnerabilities](https://realpython.com/prevent-python-sql-injection/).

Comment: i edited my entire code i figured out date picking filtering data with help of date picker able to render html table not able to get chart

Comment: lot of thanks sir you saved my life since one week i am struggling here thank you so much sir

Comment: sir initially graph is not updated anything graph is blank only, while selecting date range only it is updating can we set initially takes the recent 100 records for generating chart

Comment: Plotly.react('chart', [{ x: [/* leaving these for you to figure out */], y: [], line: { simplify: false } }], chartLayout);
anything needs to be changed here

Comment: agree to you sir, i'll try to figure it out myself thank you

Comment: sir iam not able to post new questions i am strucked in updating the results after applying new dates from date picker how can i change

Comment: account is suspended for one year sir

Comment: sir by using ajax date picker iam not able to fetch starting time values sir can you create chat room i need send the code

Comment: yes received sir